# Неправильный результат SQL запроса

Tags: mysql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему данный запрос возвращает результат,если указываю искать записи где `draft=0`

```
SELECT `messages`.*, `username`, `message_id`, `receiver_id`, `type`
FROM `messages`
JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `messages`.`sender_id`
JOIN `message_options` ON `message_options`.`message_id` = `messages`.`id`
WHERE `message` LIKE '%bcc%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `users`.`username` LIKE '%bcc%' ESCAPE '!'
AND `receiver_id` = '12016'
AND `draft` =0
AND `trash` =0
GROUP BY `message_id`
```

Comment: а `OR` не мешает? Я имею ввиду что оно будет разобрано как  `() or ( and and) `. А  `WHERE message LIKE '%bcc%' ESCAPE '!'` вроде как выполнено. Скобки попробуйте расставьте.

Comment: Да спасибо про скобки забыл

Answer (score 2):

Следует поправить запрос следующим образом

```
SELECT `messages`.*, `username`, `message_id`, `receiver_id`, `type`
FROM `messages`
JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `messages`.`sender_id`
JOIN `message_options` ON `message_options`.`message_id` = `messages`.`id`
WHERE `message` LIKE '%bcc%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `users`.`username` LIKE '%bcc%' ESCAPE '!'
AND (`receiver_id` = '12016'
     AND `draft` = 0
     AND `trash` = 0)
GROUP BY `message_id`
```